Android: Unit-Test (GPS) LocationListener using Robolectric
I want to test the location listener. Following code:
@RequiresPermission(anyOf = [permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION])
override fun getCurrentLocationFlow(): Flow<GeoLocation> = callbackFlow {
    val locationListener = LocationListener { location ->
        trySend(location.toGeoLocation()).isSuccess
    }

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
        0L,
        0f,
        locationListener
    )

    awaitClose {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener)
    }
}

The Class looks as following:
class AndroidGpsLocationProvider(
    context: Context,
    private val locationManager: LocationManager = context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
) : CurrentLocationProvider {

I want to test if the getCurrentLocationFlow gets triggered if the Location gets changed.
This is the unit-test:
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@DoNotInstrument
@Config(sdk = [29])
class AndroidGpsLocationProviderTest {
    private lateinit var locationProvider: AndroidGpsLocationProvider
    private lateinit var locationManager: LocationManager
    private lateinit var context: Context

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()
        locationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
        locationProvider = AndroidGpsLocationProvider(context, locationManager)

    }
    
    @Test
    fun `location updates should be sent to the flow`() = runBlocking {
        val testLocation = Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER).apply {
            latitude = 12.5200 // Berlin latitude
            longitude = 13.4050 // Berlin longitude
        }

        // Enable the GPS provider
        val shadowLocationManager = Shadows.shadowOf(locationManager)
        shadowLocationManager.setProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, true)

        delay(1000)


        val flow = locationProvider.getCurrentLocationFlow()

        val locationUpdates = mutableListOf<GeoLocation>()

        val job = launch {
            flow.collect { location ->
                locationUpdates.add(location)
            }
        }

        shadowLocationManager.simulateLocation(testLocation)
        shadowLocationManager.simulateLocation(Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER).apply {
            latitude = 1.5200 // Berlin latitude
            longitude = 13.4050 // Berlin longitude
        })
        shadowLocationManager.simulateLocation(Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER).apply {
            latitude = 11.5200 // Berlin latitude
            longitude = 13.4050 // Berlin longitude
        })


        delay(1000) // Reduce the delay
        job.join()

        assertEquals(1, locationUpdates.size)
        assertEquals(testLocation.latitude, locationUpdates[0].latitude, 0.0001)
        assertEquals(testLocation.longitude, locationUpdates[0].longitude, 0.0001)

        job.cancel()
    }
}

The main problem is, that the LocationListener never triggers.
The class contains a second method:
@RequiresPermission(anyOf = [permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION])
override fun getLastKnownLocation(): GeoLocation? {
    return locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)?.toGeoLocation()
}

If this method gets called after the shadowLocationManager.simulateLocation(testLocation) is called, the correct location is returned. But the onLocationChanged of the LocationLister never gets triggered.
